# Where is my mistake?

Tags: vb.net

I have table which is connected to datagridview and I would like to enter new data by using text boxes. I have following code but it gives me error. Will be appreciated if you help me. Error Message is : Use the "new" keyword to create an object instance

```
                Dim meter As DataTable = Me.DataSet1.Tables.Item("tblmeters")
                Dim row As DataRow = meter.NewRow()
                row.Item("No") = Me.txtno.Text
                row.Item("Turnover") = Me.txtturnover.Text
                row.Item("Total Win") = Me.txttotalwin.Text
                row.Item("Games Played") = Me.txtgamesplayed.Text
                row.Item("Credit In") = Me.txtcreditin.Text
                row.Item("Bill In") = Me.txtbillin.Text
                row.Item("Hand Pay") = Me.txthandpay.Text
                row.Item("Date") = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString
                meter.Rows.Add(row)
                Me.TblMeterTableAdapter.Update(Me.DataSet1.tblMeter)
                meter.AcceptChanges()
```

Comment: Please put your code in a code bracket so it's readable.

Comment: Please use the code formatting. Can you give the specific error message that you get?

Comment: Please specify the exact error you receive and where/when you get it.

Comment: It's generally useful to supply the error text when you're asking for help.

Comment: Error Message is : Use the "new" keyword to create an object instance

Thanks

Comment: [ Dim row As DataRow = meter.NewRow() ] on that line gives me error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `Me.DataSet1.Tables.Item("tblmeters")` returns `Nothing`. Make sure that `DataSet1` indeed contains table `tblmeters`.

Comment: That's the only thing I could think of, but coming from a C# background I would have expected a null reference exception.

Comment: What a stupid I am. You were right Anton. table name was tblmeter

Thaks for helping me.